# SailsJS. Custom /api URL for JSON

Tags: sails.js

Currently, I am using `localhost:1337/users` to render a view with a table to show users's data.

How can I get a custom URL for example `localhost:1337/api/users` to output JSON data.

SailsJS does blueprint automatically but after showing the view thru the controller, the JSON output gets overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Blueprint target syntax. You need to add in `config/routes.js`

```
'GET /api/users': {model:'users', blueprint: 'find'}
```

or something similar.

If you want to return JSON from controller you should create second controller method calling same model method.

`UserController.js`

```
getUsersJson: function(req, res){
    Users.get(params,function(errors,results){
        res.json(results);
    });
}
```

`config/routes.js`

```
'GET /api/users': 'UserController.getUsersJson'
```